# Python-PyQt5-How can I make an animation or transition that make an entire widget to move to other place of the screen

Tags: python-3.x, animation, pyqt5

The main idea is to move an entire QWidget to other places of the screen with a transition, or make an entry with the widget from the sides of the screen.How would I do it ? I think it would be more like a transition. I know how to work with PyQt5 but i cannot find any documentation on animation( If you know about any please post it)

Comment: Do you have a kind of animation in mind?

Comment: yes, its very simple, that a widget came from the left side of the screen an goes to the middle. i also has seen that almost all animations examples are after the execution command(if __name__ == '__main__'), why dont put it into a class.

Comment: I do not understand you, What kind of transition do you want? now your question is too broad, which is off-topic in SO.

Comment: the transition i want its like windows notifications, that slides from the screen's right side.

Comment: I think that for us to understand you record a video of the effect and share the link of the video.